# Guetzli on Ubuntu - segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to run [guetzli](https://github.com/google/guetzli) from the command line on Ubuntu server 16.04.

I have downloaded the binary from [here](https://github.com/google/guetzli/releases) and copied to a folder I have created: /var/myfolder.

According to the documentation, the command or program name is guetzli.
The file name is guetzli_linux_x86-64. I have given each folder/file 777 rights.

Navigating to /var/myfolder I've tried:

- guetzli -h *(responds with command not found)*
- ./guetzli -h *(responds with command not found)*
- guetzli_linux_x86-64 -h *(responds with command not found)*
- ./guetzli_linux_x86-64 -h *(responds with Segmentation fault (core dumped))*

The last command seems like the one that might eventually work, but I don't know why I'm getting this segmentation fault. Could the binary be corrupt?

I have also tried sudo before each call with no luck.
I suspect that I need to register the script somewhere or need to provide further access?

I have it working on my windows machine with no problems (with the windows binary of course) but I'm a noob on linux. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Ubuntu VM and guetzli runs fine in this.
It must have been an issue with the other Ubuntu VM. Strange though.